# Issue while adding a new maven module to a maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I've added a new maven module B to an existing maven project A.

Apart from module B, A contains additional 2 modules C & D.

I've properly defined the module B inside parent pom.xml.

I've also added the parent tag inside module B pom.xml. The versions of all the modules as the parent are 0.0.X-SNAPSHOT.

Now when I do a **mvn clean install deploy**, it always throws exception:

Failed to create archive: Could not find artifact B:jar:0.0.X-SNAPSHOT in central (https://nexus.xyz.com/content/groups/public) ,which kind-off makes sense.

Hence,as a last resort, I tried to manually push the file into the nexus repo using using mvn deploy:deploy-file command.

Now, if I again do **mvn clean install deploy**,it works smoothly.

But the problem re-appears when I try to release the project.
This time, it complains:

Failed to create archive: Could not find artifact B:jar:0.0.X in central (https://nexus.xyz.com/content/groups/public)

I tried with mvn clean install -U as well but in vain.

The problem doesn't appear for any other modules. 
Kindly advise.Thanks.

Comment: You may need to post the pom files of parent and `B`

Comment: Try turning on debug logging with `-X`, might help you see the issue. Also, while not solving the problem, it is not necessary to do both `install` and `deploy`. Deploy runs install by default. So specifying both phases means the majority of the build will run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...after fiddling around with all sort of permutations and combination, I finally arrived at the conclusion.
Those who says that the reactor automatically sorts and resolves all dependencies on its own are incorrect.
It seems that the link below describes it all. Kindly look at the last point under **"Reactor Sorting"** section:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html#Reactor_Sorting

It suggests that the order in which the modules are defined are taken into consideration when no other rules applies.

I hope that helps other. :)